# java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.Else Statement is not Working out

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

```
try {
                    //Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
                    //Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test","admin","admin");
                    String m=textField_1.getText();
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/logindetails","root","root");
                    //Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/logindetails","root","root");


                    String query1="Select * from Details where Username='"+m+"'";
                    PreparedStatement statement1 = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
                    ResultSet res=statement1.executeQuery(query1);
                    res.next();

                    String user;
                    user=res.getString("Username");

                    {

                        if(m.compareTo(user)==0)
                        {

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "CONNECTION SUCCESSFULL & DATA SAVED");

                            DataEntry.this.dispose();
                            login ing= new login();
                            ing.setVisible(true);



                        }

                        else
                        {   

                            String query = "insert into Details values(?,?,?,?,?)";
                            PreparedStatement statement=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                            statement.setString(1, textField.getText());


                            statement.setString(2, textField_2.getText());
                            statement.setString(3, textField_3.getText());
                            statement.setString(4, textField_1.getText());
                            statement.setString(5,String.valueOf(passwordField.getPassword()));
                            statement.execute();

                            }


                    }



                }
```

In this else part is not working.it is throwing error "Illegal operation on empty result set".I also interchange the body of both if-else statement but that does not help me out.If statement body is working properly.I think the error is ResultSet statement.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking if the `ResultSet` contains a result. Therefore you get an exception when calling `res.getString("Username")` on an empty `ResultSet`.

Change:

```
res.next();

String user;
user=res.getString("Username");
```

to:

```
String user = null;
if (res.next())
    user=res.getString("Username");
```

Then, instead of:

```
if(m.compareTo(user)==0) {
    ...
}
```

write:

```
if (user != null) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: If it doesnot include any value in ResultSet then why it is checking for if statement

Comment: @Bunky I don't understand your question. Are you saying the if statement was reached? Perhaps you should specify in your question where exactly you got the error.

Comment: In this Code my if statement body is working but else statement body is not working.Thats my question Why else statement body is not working.

Comment: @Bunky That's exactly my point. If `m.compareTo(user)==0` is true, this means that the ResultSet wasn't empty, so everything is fine. On the other hand, if the ResultSet was empty, an exception will be thrown before reaching the if-else statement.

Comment: Thanks I got your point You are saying before checking if-else statement we have to  check the resultset, Am i right.

Comment: @Bunky yes, you are